# Yii CDbCriteria Join

Tags: php, sql, yii, criteria

How I can write the query

```
SELECT *
  FROM doc_docs dd 
  JOIN doc_access da 
    ON dd.id=da.doc_id 
   AND da.user_id=7
```

with `CDbCriteria` syntax?

Comment: Maybe you'll share the solution? Or accept the answer if it is a right solution?

Comment: You should share your answer to help others.!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You actually cant completely write that since you have to apply the criteria to an activerecord model to obtain the primary table, but assuming you have a DocDocs model you can do it like this:

```
$oDBC = new CDbCriteria();
$oDBC->join = 'LEFT JOIN doc_access a ON t.id = a.doc_id and a.user_id = 7'; 

$aRecords = DocDocs::model()->findAll($oDBC);
```

Although it might be a lot easier if you give your DocDocs model a relation with doc_access, then you don't have to use the dbcriteria:

```
class DocDocs extends CActiveRecord
{
   ... 

   public function relations()
   {
      return array('access' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'DocAccess', 'doc_id');
   }

   ...
}

$oDocDocs = new DocDocs;
$oDocDocs->id = 7;
$aRecords = $oDocDocs->access;
```

Should give you a fairly good idea how to start...