# Yii left join by CDbCriteria

Tags: php, join, yii, left-join

Have two tables:

**Content**

```
 id |  text
------------
 1  | text1
 2  | text2
 3  | text3
 4  | text4
```

**Photos**

```
 id |  content_id |  src
-----------------------------
 1  |      1      |  img1.png
 2  |      1      |  img2.png
 3  |      2      |  img3.png
 4  |      3      |  img1.png
```

Trying to get content with left joined photos from third controller.

My code:

```
$oDBC = new CDbCriteria();
$oDBC->select = 't.*,p.*'; 
$oDBC->join = 'LEFT JOIN photos p ON t.id = p.content_id'; 
$oDBC->condition = 't.step_id = "'.$model->id.'"';

$content = Content::model()->find($oDBC);
```

In ContentController added function:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array('photos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Photos', 'content_id');
}
```

But `print_r($content)` returns only content data, without photos data.

Like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995486/739897) answer I tried:

```
print_r($content->photos);
```

but got `Property "Content.photos" is not defined.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: added function in contentcontroller? it should be in content model

Comment: Ahhh, I lost half of day on this. Thanks! Please add it like answer and I'll mark it solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added the relations function in the wrong place. It should be added to the `Content` model, and not `ContentController`:

```
class Content extends CActiveRecord {

    // ... other functions ...

    public function relations() {
        return array('photos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Photos', 'content_id');
    }

}
```

If you have generated your model with Gii, then the relations function should already be there.