# Getting full join by cdbcriteria yii, mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Using Cdbcriteria class of Yii how can I get full join(db is mysql)? I know that it can be achieved through union of left join and right join.....but its syntex I am not getting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4983864/2274209..

Comment: Please help..........I have to use inside search of db model

Answer (score -1):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array(
    'posts' => array(
       'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
       'together' => true,
    ),
);
$models = User::model()->findAll($criteria);

foreach($models AS $model) {
    echo $model->username;// gives you the username
    foreach($model->posts AS $post) {
       echo $post->title; // gives you the post title
    }
}
// if it's about only one user:
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('user_id', (int)$user_id);
$criteria->with = array(
   'posts' => array('together' => true, 'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'),
);
$model = User::model()->find($crieteria);
echo $model->username;
foreach ($model->posts AS $post) {
  echo $post->title;
}
// also you can:
$model = User::model()->with('posts')->findByPk((int)$user_id);
echo $model->username;
foreach($model->posts AS $post) {
  echo $post->title;
}
```

In the above example we assume we have a user table which has a one:many relation with posts table and also the posts relation is defined in the `relations()` method of Yii AR.